# Spark Driver stuck when using different windows

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm having problems with Spark (Spark 3.0.1) when trying to use use window functions over different windows.

There are no errors but the driver gets stuck when trying to show or write the dataframe (no tasks start in spark ui).

The problem happens both when running on yarn and local mode.

Example:

```
select
  col_1,
  col_2,
  col_3,
  sum(x) over (partition by col_1, col_2) s,
  max(x) over (partition by col_1, col_3) m
from table
```

My work-around so far has been to split the window functions in different queries and persist the intermediate results to parquet. Something like this:

```
df = spark.sql("select col_1, col_2, col_3, sum(x) over (partition by col_1, col_2) s from table")
df.write.parquet(path)
df = spark.read.parquet(path)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("table")

df = spark.sql("select *, max(x) over (partition by col_1, col_3) m from table")
```

But I don't want to repeat this work-around anymore